# 'kABPersonAddressStreetKey' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: use CNPostalAddress.street

Tags: ios, swift2

I have the following class written in an earlier version of Swift. The **Swift 2** Compiler warns that

'**kABPersonAddressStreetKey**' was deprecated in **iOS 9.0**: use **CNPostalAddress.street**

and gives an error

> 'Cannot find an initializer for type 'MKPlacemark' that accepts an
>   argument list of type '(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
>   addressDictionary: [String : String?])'

I realise that optionals are required to resolve the error but whatever I try does not seem to resolve the problem. This is due to me being a newbie to swift and any help would be appreciated.

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import AddressBook

class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
let title: String?
let locationName: String
let discipline: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title: String, locationName: String, discipline: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.locationName = locationName
    self.discipline = discipline
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()
}

var subtitle: String? {
    return locationName
}

// annotation callout info button opens this mapItem in Maps app
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): subtitle]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = title

    return mapItem
  }
}
```

Answer (score 36):

Replace `import AddressBook` with `import Contacts` and also replace `String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey)` with `String(CNPostalAddressStreetKey)`

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import Contacts

class Artwork: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
let title: String?
let locationName: String
let discipline: String
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title: String, locationName: String, discipline: String,       coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.title = title
    self.locationName = locationName
    self.discipline = discipline
    self.coordinate = coordinate

    super.init()
}

var subtitle: String? {
    return locationName
}

// annotation callout info button opens this mapItem in Maps app
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDictionary = [String(CNPostalAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle!]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = title

    return mapItem

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

1. `import Contacts` instead `import AddressBook`.
2. `CNPostalAddressStreetKey` instead `kABPersonAddressStreetKey`.

Comment: This is an old question with an already highly-upvoted answer.  How does your answer differer from the accepted answer?

Comment: This answer adds value for objective-c.  `CNPostalAddressStreetKey` is the objective-c version of swift's `CNPostalAddress.street`

Answer (score 2):

Filed a Radar on this. Got this response today:

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue:
>   Please know that you should continue to use the deprecated keys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your subtitle as AnyObject as shown below:

let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle as! AnyObject]

and your complete code for "func mapItem() -> MKMapItem { }" will be:

```
func mapItem() -> MKMapItem {
    let addressDict = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): self.subtitle as! AnyObject]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: self.coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDict)

    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = self.title

    return mapItem
  }
```