# CLPlacemark addressDictionary keys on iOS 9

Tags: ios, core-location, ios9, abperson, clplacemark

[Reading the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/index.html), Apple points to [ABPerson](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/index.html) for the keys to use on `CLPlacemark`'s  `addressDictionary`.

But since iOS 9, `ABPerson` is deprecated.

Is there something else to use for the keys ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['kABPersonAddressStreetKey' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: use CNPostalAddress.street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085299/kabpersonaddressstreetkey-was-deprecated-in-ios-9-0-use-cnpostaladdress-stree)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure some of them out for a problem I've been having:

```
@"City" -> CLPlacemark.city
@"State" -> CLPlacemark.administrativeArea
@"Country" -> CLPlacemark.country
```

See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669356/extending-clplacemark-results-in-exc-bad-access/32670795#32670795).